# How to get text within div to be relative to the div's width and height, CSS, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the text within a div to be relative to the size of the div, so that when you zoom in the text gets bigger along with the div, and when you zoom out the text gets smaller along with the div. For example, if you hit ctr and - at the same time on stackoverflow, and zoom out to 25%, you can see that the text shrinks along with the div, all the way to 25%, as oppose to just the text shrinking or just the div shrinking - they shrink at the same time. I'm trying to get something of that effect. Thanks.

```
div {
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
font-size: 12%;
}

<div> Text </div>
```

Comment: Isn't that feature built-in in all browsers already?

Comment: @Teemu It's not if your html code isn't making it so.

Comment: Have you try to use dynamic font-size unit (em)

Comment: check this for relative font sizes http://www.sitepoint.com/new-css3-relative-font-size/

Comment: @Alexis Okay. Here's the problem. When I zoom in, the div doesn't increase in size along with the text.

Comment: @Teemu, please see my comment to someone's answer belong to see what I need it to be like.

Comment: @LuthandoLoot Please take a look at my comments below.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood your question, but you really [don't need anything](http://jsfiddle.net/0gy7n9j9/) to achieve this ...

Comment: @Teemu Um, yeah. That's because sites like stackoverflow and jsfiddle's coding automatically does that for you. Whatever is inside their divs get auto-adjusted when you zoom in or out. It's not like that when you make your own website. Either the divs gets change, and the text remain the same, or the text gets change and the div remains the same.

Comment: @frosty ??? There's no such of coding, it works everywhere, unless you don't have some CSS preventing it.

Comment: @Teemu Like I said. It only works that way on JSFiddle because their site codes auto-adjust all their divs and everything inside their divs. Try it on a web server or local host and see the difference.

Comment: @frosty I can't see any difference when running this locally. Though, if you've set `width: 50%`, that will stand nevertheless of the zooming level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `em` based `font-size` show as below it will be relative.

Please check working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vasimkp/r2vhcfj5/embedded/result/).

```
body {
    font-size: 16px;  /* declare base font-size. */
}

div {
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
font-size: 1em;
}
```

Comment: You see when you zoom out the div doesn't get smaller? Or when you zoom in, the div doesn't get bigger?

Comment: I need the div to get bigger or smaller when you zoom in or out.

Comment: And the text inside along with it.

Comment: I tried this CSS in fiddle it works on zoom in/out. Ex. Link : https://jsfiddle.net/vasimkp/r2vhcfj5/embedded/result/

Comment: Can you try to post screenshot of both scenario which you are talking about ?

Comment: Okay. Right now there's only the word "text" inside. But what if you have more than 1 word. What if you have like 20 words "text", inside, and you zoom in to 500%, do you see what happens? They don't fit inside the div anymore, because the div is not big enough. The div needs to auto-stretch to fit the words like stackoverflow. Try zooming in on stackoverflow, and you'll see that the words never go beyond the boundary of their divs.

Comment: Also, do you see what happens when you zoom out? The div didn't get smaller. It stayed the same width. But try that on stackoverflow, and see what happens? The divs gets smaller every time you zoom out, until you hit 25%.

Answer (score 0):

Try the fiddle at 
http://jsfiddle.net/meghanagpal/fgoyt0ze/1/

```
HTML
<div>some text</div>
CSS
html {    
    font-size: 100%;  /* this is usually 16px by default*/
}

body { font-size: 0.75em; // 12px }

div {
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
font-size: 1em;
color:#ff0000;
}
```

and customize the fonts for the body and div as per your needs.